# Get Node for XML with namespace using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, automationanywhere

I am attempting to select a node based on a value in an element in an xml file that contains a namespace.

I am using Automation Anywhere's Get XML Node command that limits me to using a single line XPath statement.

This is the sample xml file

```
<IMPORT xmlns="urn:Import">
    <STUFF>
        <STUFF_TYPE>
            <STUFF_TYPE_KEY>1</STUFF_TYPE_KEY>
        </STUFF_TYPE>
        <WALMART>
            <STORE>
                <STORE_ID TYPE="SC" ID="SC-12345">WM000001</STORE_ID>
                <STORE_STATUS>O</STORE_STATUS>
            </STORE>
        </WALMART> 
    </STUFF>
</IMPORT>
```

I would like to select the STORE_STATUS value where STORE_ID = WM000001

Right now, it is not finding the node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a namespace agnostic expression like

```
//*[local-name() = 'STORE']/*[local-name() = 'STORE_ID' and text() = 'WM000001']/../*[local-name() = 'STORE_STATUS']
```

This selects the `STORE_STATUS` element from all `STORE` elements with `STORE_ID` children which have the value `WM000001`. If you only want the value, add a `/text()` to the end of the expression.

Comment: Getting the following error: '//*[namespace-uri()='urn:Import' and local-name() = 'STORE']/*[namespace-uri()='urn:Import' and local-name() = 'STORE_ID' and text()='WM000001']/DefaultNSPrefix:../*[namespace-uri()='urn:Import' and local-name() = 'STORE_STATUS']' has an invalid qualified name. I assume because the `..` used to walk back up a level and select the STORE_STATUS is not tied to a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working:

```
//*[local-name() = 'STORE']/*[local-name() = 'STORE_ID' and text() = 'WM000001']/following-sibling::*[local-name() = 'STORE_STATUS']
```